# Get connection id using BrainSocket for Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, ratchet

Hopefully a simple question and I'm just blind: I'm implementing [BrainSocket](https://github.com/BrainBoxLabs/brain-socket) by BrainBoxLabs (a websocket handler for Laravel which apparently uses Ratchet). Everything's peachy, but I can't seem to figure out how to access the connection ID (on either end, but primarly server-side).

Obviously it must be tracked, and when a client sends a message to the server, the server log shows the connection id, but the documentation on the GitHub repo is limited and I don't see the command for me to access it. I suppose in a broader sense, I can't see how to use BS to fire events that only specific connections will see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, BrainSocket does not currently support pushes. So, sadness.